# Convert postgres raw query to Django ORM query and group by

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a raw Postgresql query which needs to be converted to Django ORM query.

I was able to execute the query in Postgres and see the expected result. I'm getting 5 records for the raw query on postgres DB.

But when I execute the Django ORM query, it's not giving the expected output. I'm getting 78 results for the ORM query in postgres.

Please let me know where am I making mistake in Django ORM query.

**Raw postgres query:**

```
select customer_id, program_id, project_id, store_id, count(store_id) 
from public.alerts_alert where (customer_id=2 and program_id=134 and project_id=1364) 
group by customer_id, program_id, project_id, store_id
```

**Django ORM query:**

```
queryset = Alert.objects.filter(**filter_params).annotate(
            customer_name=F('customer__name'),
            program_name=F('program__name'),
            project_name=F('project__name'),
            store_count=Count('store')
        )
```

`**filter_params` is where I'll be providing actual values as mentioned in raw queryset.

**Edit1:**

This is what I'm getting when I try to print `queryset.query`.

```
SELECT "alerts_alert"."time_created", "alerts_alert"."time_modified", "alerts_alert"."registered_timestamp", "alerts_alert"."id", "alerts_alert"."title", "alerts_alert"."content", "alerts_alert"."alert_date", "alerts_alert"."expiration_date", "alerts_alert"."current_status_id", "alerts_alert"."customer_id", "alerts_alert"."store_id", "alerts_alert"."program_id", "alerts_alert"."project_id", "alerts_alert"."visit_id", "alerts_alert"."batch_id", COUNT("alerts_alert"."store_id") AS "store_count", "programs_program"."name" AS "program_name", "projects_project"."name" AS "project_name", "customers_account"."name" AS "customer_name" FROM "alerts_alert" INNER JOIN "projects_project" ON ("alerts_alert"."project_id" = "projects_project"."id") INNER JOIN "customers_account" ON ("alerts_alert"."customer_id" = "customers_account"."id") INNER JOIN "programs_program" ON ("alerts_alert"."program_id" = "programs_program"."id") WHERE ("alerts_alert"."expiration_date" IS NULL AND "alerts_alert"."project_id" = 1364 AND "alerts_alert"."customer_id" = 2 AND "alerts_alert"."program_id" = 134 AND "alerts_alert"."unregistered_timestamp" IS NULL) GROUP BY "alerts_alert"."id", "programs_program"."name", "projects_project"."name", "customers_account"."name"
```

I don't know why, but for some reason, django query set is adding `id` column to the `group by` clause even though I didn't specify it.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```py
queryset = Alert.objects.filter(**filter_params).values(
            'customer_id', 
            'program_id', 
            'project_id', 
            'store_id').annotate(
              customer_name=F('customer__name'),
              program_name=F('program__name'),
              project_name=F('project__name'),
              store_count=Count('store')
           )
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm able to achieve it using `Sum()` instead of `Count()`.